# What is the probability that after the first round of bubble, the 10th element is in the 20th address?

Tags: probability

Consider a bubble sort algorithm dealing with 1~100. What is the probability that after the first round of bubble, the 10th element is in the 20th address?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that we are "bubbling up" the larger element in each step, the only way for the 10th element to end up in the 20th address is if it was initially in the 21st position and then got pushed downwards because of a larger element in the 1st and 20th address "bubbled up". Since there will always be an element greater than 10 placed within the first 20 positions in the initial array, this is guaranteed. Hence, the probability is 1/100.